# Are synaptic boutons always located on axons?

Tags: neuroscience, synapses, neuron

I am learning about the protein Synaptophysin and I have read that it is an integral membrane protein localised to synaptic vesicles. I have also read that it is a specific and sensitive marker for synaptic terminals. On this [site](https://faculty.washington.edu/chudler/synapse.html), I have read that synaptic terminals are the presynaptic endings and on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_synapse#:%7E:text=The%20presynaptic%20axon%20terminal%2C%20or,such%20as%20mitochondria%20and%20endoplasmic) that the presynaptic axon terminal is also known as the synaptic bouton. From what I have read online it seems to me that synaptic boutons are located only on axons.

However, I have found out about dendrodendritic synapses which are connections between the dendrites of two different neurons. Can the presynaptic ending of a dendrodendritic synapse be referred to as a synaptic bouton or are synaptic boutons only located on axons? Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axonal boutons are named as such due to their shape. Dendro-dendritic synapses do not resemble this shape and are never referred to as boutons. It does not appear that synaptophysin is expressed on dendrites ([Fletcher et al. 1991](https://www.jneurosci.org/content/11/6/1617)), but I am unaware of a study that targeted dendro-dendritic synapses specifically.

---

**References**

Fletcher, TL, P Cameron, P De Camilli, and G Banker. ‘The Distribution of Synapsin I and Synaptophysin in Hippocampal Neurons Developing in Culture’. The Journal of Neuroscience 11, no. 6 (1 June 1991): 1617. https://doi.org/10.1523/JNEUROSCI.11-06-01617.1991.